# React variable not reactive in external event

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reactive-programming, codemirror

I'm a Vue developer that's trying to do a React App.

I'm trying to wrap CodeMirror in a React app and I'm running into some troubles. Not sure how to fix it.

I'm instantiating a CodeMirror editor and attaching some event handlers to it.
Those handlers are like so:
When you focus the editor, the `isFocused` variable becomes `true`.
When you focus out of the editor, the `isFocused` variable becomes `false`.
When you type in the editor you should do some action if the `isFocused` variable is true.

In the last handler, I need to access a **reactive** variable set with `useState` (`isFocused`).
That variable is not reactive in the context of that function. It's read as the default value `false`.

The component looks something like this:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css'
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript'
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const textArea = useRef()
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState('sample data')
  

  const handleChange = () => {
      console.log('isFocused->', isFocused);

    if (isFocused) {
     // do something here 
    }
  }

  const handleEditorFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true)
  }

  const handleEditorBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea.current)
    editor.on('change', handleChange)
    editor.on('focus', handleEditorFocus)
    editor.on('blur', handleEditorBlur)

    return () => {
      editor.toTextArea()
    } 
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isFocused ? 'focused' : 'not focused'}
      <textarea
        ref={textArea}
        value={data}
        onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
    )
};

export default App;
```

Please point me in the right direction with this issue.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
I even made a repl.it [here](https://replit.com/@adrianthedev/No-reactivity#src/App.js).

**UPDATE 2**
A better demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dvaqje?file=src/App.js).
I basically need to have access to the `instance` and `change` params in the `handleChange` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `useEffect` function with a callback to `handleChange` and pass it `isFocused` as an argument.

**PS:** Don't forget `Boolean()` to display the state of isFocused otherwise it returns an object.

(See the demo link at the bottom of the page )

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';
import 'codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript';
import CodeMirror from 'codemirror';

export default function App() {
  const textArea = useRef();
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState('sample data');

  const handleChange = isF => { 
    console.log('isFocused->', Boolean(isF));           // here

    if (isFocused) {
      // ...
    }
  };

  const handleEditorFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };

  const handleEditorBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {                                     // here
    handleChange(isFocused);
  }, [isFocused]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textArea.current);
    editor.on('change', handleChange);
    editor.on('focus', handleEditorFocus);
    editor.on('blur', handleEditorBlur);

    return () => {
      editor.toTextArea();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isFocused ? 'focused' : 'not focused'}
      <textarea
        ref={textArea}
        value={data}
        onChange={e => setData(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-clyeej)

Comment: The above example is a bit different than my scenario. In the event handlers you are **setting** the state (which will work). In my example I need to fetch the state and it's not reactive.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that the `handleChange` method gets two params from CodeMirror `instance` and `change`.
I updated your stackblitz to include those like so:

`const handleChange = (isF, instance, change)`

Now it works. `isF` is reactive inside that function and the `instance` and `change` params get passed to the method. I just don't know how :)

I mean... This solves my problem but I don't know how React does it.

Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Honestly, I can't explain why. Maybe it's related to the 2 change event listeners on the same component : onChange and on. ('Change', ...) ???

Comment: I'm getting back to this. It's not actually working. Check my example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dvaqje?file=src/App.js).

When the callback from codemirror runs, the `isFocused` variable is still non-reactive.

Comment: @adrianthedev My solution answered your question. Your code has changed so the problem too. Instead of asking a question, accepting a solution, changing your code, rejecting the solution, etc. I suggest you take a look at the `react-codemirror` and `react-codemirror2` packages, they might exist for a good reason.

Comment: Sorry man, I didn't want to do that (ask, change, ask again). I just forgot to mention those attributes.

Comment: I selected you answer as correct. I'm actually really trying to fix this issue.

Comment: @adrianthedev the problem is caused by `instance`, remove this argument from the handleChange function and check your console.

Comment: @adrianthedev In your example, the `instance` argument already returns the value of change. That's why if you put both it doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the question with a better example forked from your solution for clarity sake (so only talking about the stackblitz example from now on).

If I remove the `instance` param from the `handleChange` method I don't have access to it. 
I need to have access to it and have the `isFocused`  variable reactive.